# Changing color dots to show what currently is showing on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have section where I show most recently news. I'm using arrows to scroll throught these news. I wanted to add some dots to show the users on which text they're on. I want for active dot to change color and it's working but only when I'm going forward. When I want to go back to the previous news, same dot stay active. How can I fix that?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const dotsContainer = document.getElementById("dots");
  const scrollText = document.getElementById("bannerText");

  for (let i = 0; i < scrollText.children.length; i++) {
    const dot = document.createElement("div");
    dot.classList.add("dot");
    dotsContainer.appendChild(dot);
    dot.addEventListener("click", function() {
      scrollToChild(i);
    });
  }

  let currentIndex = 0;

  window.scrollLeft = function() {
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
      currentIndex--;
    } else {
      currentIndex = scrollText.children.length - 1;
    }
    scrollToChild(currentIndex);
  };

  window.scrollRight = function() {
    if (currentIndex < scrollText.children.length - 1) {
      currentIndex++;
    } else {
      currentIndex = 0;
    }
    scrollToChild(currentIndex);
  };

  let isArrowScroll = false;
  scrollText.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (isArrowScroll) {
      const childIndex = Math.round(scrollText.scrollTop /
        scrollText.children[0].offsetHeight);
      currentIndex = childIndex;
      updateDots();
    }
  });


  function scrollToChild(index) {
    currentIndex = index;
    updateDots();
    const child = scrollText.children[index];
    scrollText.scrollTo({
      top: child.offsetTop,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }

  function updateDots() {
    const dots = dotsContainer.querySelectorAll(".dot");
    dots.forEach((dot, index) => {
      if (index === currentIndex) {
        dot.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        dot.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "ArrowUp" || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
      isArrowScroll = true;
    }
  });

  scrollText.addEventListener("scrollend", function() {
    isArrowScroll = false;
  });

  updateDots();
});
```

```css
.color {
  top: 25rem;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(212, 239, 237, 0.8);
  font-family: 'title';
  width: 50rem;
  text-align: center;
  height: 16rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.color::before,
.color::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11.25rem;
}

.color::before {
  border-color: rgba(212, 239, 237, 0.8) transparent transparent transparent;
  right: -11.25rem;
  top: -11.25rem;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.color::after {
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(212, 239, 237, 0.8) transparent;
  left: -11.25rem;
  bottom: -11.25rem;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*odstep miedzy wierszami*/
}

.title .text-item1 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.news {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex: 6;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cover {
  display: flex;
}

.scroll-text {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(109, 173, 168, 0.9);
  font-weight: 580;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 51rem;
  height: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.child {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  margin: 0.6rem 1rem 0 1rem;
  white-space: wrap;
  display: flex;
  animation: slideText 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.child:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.icon {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes slideText {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

#scroll-left,
#scroll-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

#scroll-left {
  left: -4rem;
}

#scroll-right {
  right: -4rem;
}

.icon i {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #6DADA8;
}

.icon:hover i {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #37635f;
}

.dots-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dot {
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #6DADA8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
}

.dot.active {
  background-color: #0e3066;
}
```

```html
<div class="a0">
  <div class="color">
    <div class="title">
      <span class="text-item1">News</span>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
      <div class="cover">
        <button id="scroll-left" class="icon" onclick="scrollLeft()"><i class="fa-solid fa-angles-left"></i></i></button>

        <div class="scroll-text" id="bannerText">
          <div class="child">text1</div>
          <div class="child">text2</div>
          <div class="child">text3</div>
          <div class="child">text4</div>
        </div>
        <button id="scroll-right" class="icon" onclick="scrollRight()"><i     class="fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i></button>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="dots" class="dots-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi mymoonluna and welcome to SO. Please add the necessary code to replicate the issue so we can help you look for a solution.

Comment: While the code shown here is helpful it doesn't reproduce any arrow events for the `.scroll-text` element, or its children. Could you please [edit] your question once more to add the relevant code?

Comment: this is all i have in css with this section

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to use scrollLeft name for function, just rename function in scrollLeft2, also I changed buttons to be visible in snippets.

```js
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const dotsContainer = document.getElementById("dots");
        const scrollText = document.getElementById("bannerText");

        for (let i = 0; i < scrollText.children.length; i++) {
          const dot = document.createElement("div");
          dot.classList.add("dot");
          dotsContainer.appendChild(dot);
          dot.addEventListener("click", function () {
            scrollToChild(i);
          });
        }

        let currentIndex = 0;
        window.scrollLeft2 = function () {
          if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex--;
          } else {
            currentIndex = scrollText.children.length - 1;
          }
          scrollToChild(currentIndex);
        };

        window.scrollRight = function () {
          if (currentIndex < scrollText.children.length - 1) {
            currentIndex++;
          } else {
            currentIndex = 0;
          }
          scrollToChild(currentIndex);
        };

        let isArrowScroll = false;
        scrollText.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
          if (isArrowScroll) {
            const childIndex = Math.round(scrollText.scrollTop / scrollText.children[0].offsetHeight);
            currentIndex = childIndex;
            updateDots();
          }
        });

        function scrollToChild(index) {
          currentIndex = index;
          updateDots();
          const child = scrollText.children[index];
          scrollText.scrollTo({
            top: child.offsetTop,
            behavior: "smooth",
          });
        }

        function updateDots() {
          const dots = dotsContainer.querySelectorAll(".dot");
          dots.forEach((dot, index) => {
            if (index === currentIndex) {
              dot.classList.add("active");
            } else {
              dot.classList.remove("active");
            }
          });
        }

        window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
          if (event.key === "ArrowUp" || event.key === "ArrowDown") {
            isArrowScroll = true;
          }
        });

        scrollText.addEventListener("scrollend", function () {
          isArrowScroll = false;
        });

        updateDots();
      });
```

```css
.color {
        top: 25rem;
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(212, 239, 237, 0.8);
        font-family: "title";
        width: 50rem;
        text-align: center;
        height: 16rem;
        margin: auto;
      }

      .color::before,
      .color::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 11.25rem;
      }

      .color::before {
        border-color: rgba(212, 239, 237, 0.8) transparent transparent transparent;
        right: -11.25rem;
        top: -11.25rem;
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        z-index: -1;
      }

      .color::after {
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(212, 239, 237, 0.8) transparent;
        left: -11.25rem;
        bottom: -11.25rem;
        transform: rotate(135deg);
        z-index: -1;
      }

      .title {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        line-height: 1.3;
        /*odstep miedzy wierszami*/
      }

      .title .text-item1 {
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
        color: #000;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: 10px;
      }

      .news {
        position: relative;
        color: #000;
        display: flex;
        flex: 6;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .cover {
        display: flex;
      }

      .scroll-text {
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgba(109, 173, 168, 0.9);
        font-weight: 580;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        width: 51rem;
        height: 7rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 1rem;
      }

      .child {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
        margin: 0.6rem 1rem 0 1rem;
        white-space: wrap;
        display: flex;
        animation: slideText 0.5s ease-in-out;
      }

      .child:first-child {
        display: block;
      }

      .icon {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      @keyframes slideText {
        from {
          opacity: 0;
          transform: translateX(20%);
        }
        to {
          opacity: 1;
          transform: translateX(0%);
        }
      }

      #scroll-left,
      #scroll-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3rem;
        font-size: 0.75rem;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
      }

      #scroll-left {
        left: -4rem;
      }

      #scroll-right {
        right: -4rem;
      }

      .icon i {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
        color: #6dada8;
      }

      .icon:hover i {
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        color: #37635f;
      }

      .dots-container {
        display: flex;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .dot {
        width: 0.5rem;
        height: 0.5rem;
        background-color: #6dada8;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 0 0.2rem;
      }

      .dot.active {
        background-color: #0e3066;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="a0">
      <div class="color">
        <div class="title">
          <span class="text-item1">News</span>
        </div>
        <div class="news">
          <div class="cover">
            <button id="scroll-left" class="icon" onclick="scrollLeft2()"><i class="fa-solid fa-angles-left"><</i></button>

            <div class="scroll-text" id="bannerText">
              <div class="child">text1</div>
              <div class="child">text2</div>
              <div class="child">text3</div>
              <div class="child">text4</div>
            </div>
            <button id="scroll-right" class="icon" onclick="scrollRight()"><i class="fa-solid fa-angles-right">></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dots" class="dots-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```